# DDD Domain Entities using external Services

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-service

In DDD, you're strongly encouraged to have all business logic within the domain entities instead of separate from it. Which makes sense.

You also have the idea of Domain Services to encapsulate certain pieces of logic.

What I can't work out is how to have the domain entities perform their business logic that itself depends on external services.

Take, for example, a user management system. In this there is a `User` domain entity, on which there are various business actions to perform. One of these is `verify_email_address` - which sends an email to the users email address in order to verify that it's valid.

Except that sending an email involves interactions with external services. So it seems reasonable for this logic to be encapsulated within a Domain Service that the `User` entity then makes use of. But how does it actually do this?

I've seen some things suggest that the `User` entity is constructed with references to every domain service that it needs. Which makes it quite big and bloated, and especially hard to test.

I've seen some things that suggest that you should pass in the domain service to the method that you are calling - which just feels weird. Why would someone outside of the domain entity need to pass in the `EmailClient` service when calling `verify_email_address`?

I've also then seen the suggestion that you instead pass the `User` entity in to the domain service, except that this seems to imply that the logic is in the domain service and not the entity.

And finally, I've seen suggestions that the entity should raise a domain event to trigger the email, which the domain service then reacts to. That means that all of the logic for whether to send the email or not - no need if it's already verified - and which email address to send it to are in the right place, and it also means that the user only needs a way to raise events and nothing more. So it feels less tightly coupled. But it also means you need a whole eventing mechanism, which is itself quite complicated.

So, am I missing something here? How can I achieve this?

(I'm working in Rust if that matters, but I don't see that it should)

Answer (score 1):

> What I can't work out is the best way to have the domain entities perform their business logic that itself depends on external services.

That's not your fault; the literature is a mess.

---

> In DDD, you're strongly encouraged to have all business logic within the domain entities instead of separate from it.

That's not *quite* right; the common idea is that all business logic belongs within the domain *layer* (somewhere).  But that doesn't necessarily mean that the logic must be within a domain *entity*.

Evans, in Chapter 5, writes:

> In some cases, the clearest and most pragmatic design includes operations that do not belong to any object.  Rather than force the issue, we can follow the natural contours of the problems space and include SERVICES explicitly in the model.
>
> There are important domain operations that can't find a natural home in an ENTITY or VALUE OBJECT....

It's a very [Kingdom of Nouns](https://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html) idea; we have code that actually does something useful, so there *must* be an object it can belong to.

Having a module (in the [Parnas](https://kilthub.cmu.edu/articles/journal_contribution/On_the_criteria_to_be_used_in_decomposing_systems_into_modules/6607958) sense) in the domain layer that is responsible for the coordination of an email client and a domain entity (or for that matter, a repository) to achieve some goal is a perfectly reasonable option.

---

Could that module be the domain entity itself?  It certainly could.

You might find, however, that coupling the management of the in-memory representation of domain information and the orchestration of a domain process that interacts with "the real world", as it were, complicates your maintenance responsibilities by introducing a heavy coupling between two distinct concepts that should instead be lightly coupled.

Clean Architecture (and the predecessors in that lineage) suggests to separate "entities" from "use cases".  Ivar Jacobson's Objectory Process distinguished "entities" from "controls".  So the notion of a service that is decoupled from the entity shouldn't be too alien.

---

Ruth Malan writes:

> Design is what we do when we want to get more of what we want than we'd get by just doing it.

Finding the right design depends a lot on finding the right "what we want" for our local context (including our best guess at how this local context is going to evolve over the time window we care about).

Answer (score 1):

VoiceOfUnReason has a perfectly valid answer.

I just want to boil down your question to the grits.

> What I can't work out is how to have the domain entities perform their business logic that itself depends on external services.

> I've also then seen the suggestion that you instead pass the User entity in to the domain service, except that this seems to imply that the logic is in the domain service and not the entity.

That's the key. All logic that belongs to domain entities should be done on domain entities. But at the same time, domain entities MUST be independent of the outside world (even other domain entities).

That's why we have domain services and application services.

Domain services are used to coordinate things between multiple entities, like transferring money between two accounts:

```cs
public class TransferService
{
   IAccountRepos _repos;

   public void Transfer(string fromAccountNumber, string toAccountNumber, decimal amount)
   {
       var account1 = _repos.Get(fromAccountNumber);
       var account2 = _repos.Get(fromAccountNumber);
       var money = account1.Withdraw(amount);
       account2.Deposit(money);
       _repos.Update(account1);
       _repos.Update(account2);
   }
}
```

That's a domain service since it's still only using the domain only.

Application services on the other hand are used to communicate over boundaries and with external services.

And it's an external service that you should create in this case. It looks similar to domain services but are at a layer over it (it can use domain services to solve its purpose).

To summarize:

- Entities must be used to perform actions on themself (the easiest way is to make all setters private which forces you to add methods).
- Domains services should be used as soon as two or more entities must be used to solve a problem (can even be two entities of the same type as in the example above)
- Application services are used to interact with things outside the domain and can use entities and/or domain services to solve the problem.

Comment: It's interesting that you say "Entities must be used to perform actions on themself" because that actually does clear a number of things up. I'd had it in my head that you should use entities to perform actions relating to them, which isn't quite the same thing.

Comment: In this case, it still gets a little bit confused because there's a portion of the decision that seems like it belongs to the entity - can the email be verified, and if so which one - but then there's a portion that can't be done there, so the logic gets split between two places. But that can be managed :)

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to design a bank transfer as an aggregate in the example above? Which could have references to two accounts modelled as simple entities? The reason I am asking is that it seems that both accounts seem to use the same database, and the transfer could and I believe should be strongly consistent, to avoid failure in the second repo update. Could a domain service guarantee strong consistency somehow?

Comment: Antonis: transactions

Comment: As I think, the actual `transfer` action on your aggregate is not just running `withdraw` and `deposit` side by side. How about "Transfer" aggregate mentioned above, with entities called as follows `account1.transferMoneyTo(money, account2)`?